# ¿Qué hace "range(len(s) -1, -1, -1)" en Python?

Tags: python, bucle-for

Vi el siguiente código y estoy intentando entenderlo:

```
s = ['Azucar', 'yerba', 'Fideos', 'Yogurt', 'Quesos', 'Mermelada']
l = []
for x in range(len(s) -1, -1, -1): 
    l += s[x]

print(l)
```

Obviamente, yo quiero iterar desde el último índice hacia el 0 y este código puede hacerlo, pero no entiendo el fragmento `range(len(s) -1, -1, -1):`

¿Alguien lo podria explicar, por favor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el código de tu ejemplo tenemos un ciclo definido por **`for`**, donde la variable **`X`** es usada para trabajar con valores dentro del rango definido por *(inicio, fin, paso)*, donde en tu caso tenemos:

```
inicio = len(s)-1

fin = -1

paso = -1
```

Es decir, que **`x`** empezará con el valor **`len(s)-1`**, el bucle continuará hasta llegar al valor **`-1`** y a cada paso se le restará **`-1`**.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 1):

Recuerda que ***range*** es un rango el cual le indicas un inicio y un final y un comportamiento, en tu código tenemos que

```
range(len(s) -1, -1, -1)
```

Esto me indica que empiezo desde la longitud de la lista menos 1 (por que recuerda que se cuentan las listas desde 0 mas no desde 1) hasta la posición posición 0, ponen menos 1 porque el ultimo numero nunca lo toma, es decir si pones desde 0 hasta 4, el tomara hasta 3, y si tomas desde 5 hasta -1 tomará el 0, y el ultimo parámetro me indica el comportamiento del rango.

Si colocas -1 indicas que vaya restando el rango es decir 5,4,3,2,1, normalmente nosotros un rango en un for lo ponemos así por ejemplo:

```
For i in range(0,4)
```

Casi nunca ponemos el ultimo parámetro que sería 1( esto porque python ya lo trae por defecto), es decir que vaya incrementando de a 1, pero puedes modificar este parámetro para el comportamiento para que por ejemplo sea de a 2 o de a 4.etc.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la enorme explicación. Me ayuda a tener una idea mas clara. Que tengas una gran semana.

Comment: Gracias, si te sirvio la respuesta podrias darle un punto arriba.

Answer (score 0):

Por completar las respuestas anteriores. Tu código está iterando por los índices del array, y los índices son números. De ahí que utilices `range()` para generar esos números.

Pero para hacer lo que buscas, que es crear otra lista a partir de una dada, pero con los elementos en orden inverso, no necesitas realmente los índices. En realidad no nos importa cuál es el índice de cada dato, sino sólo el valor de cada dato.

Python permite iterar *directamente por los valores*, sin necesidad de usar los índices, con la construcción `for valor in iterable`. En este caso el iterable sería la lista de partida (`s`), y la variable `valor` irá tomando los valores de cada uno de sus datos.

El problema es que queremos recorrer el iterable en orde inverso. Para esto podemos hacer `reversed(s)`. Usando estos trucos puedes escribir:

```py
s = ['Azucar', 'yerba', 'Fideos', 'Yogurt', 'Quesos', 'Mermelada']
l = []
for ingrediente in reversed(s): 
    l += ingrediente
print(l)
```

En lugar de `reversed(s)` el código anterior podría usar `s[::-1]` que es un *slice* (rodaja) de `s` que incluye todos sus elementos pero en orden inverso.

### NOTA

El código anterior produce como resultado lo mismo que el codigo de tu pregunta, pero no sé si es esto lo que esperabas. En la lista `l` obtienes algo como `['M', 'e', 'r', 'm', 'e', 'l', 'a', 'd', 'a', 'Q', 'u', 'e', 's', ...]` es decir, las letras de cada ingrediente separadamente. Sospecho que quizás tú buscabas que el resultado fuera: `['Mermelada', 'Quesos', 'Yogurt', 'Fideos', 'yerba', 'Azucar']`

Para que el resultado fuese el segundo, no debes usar `l += ingrediente`, sino `l += [ingrediente]` o bien, de forma más clara `l.append(ingrediente)`. La razón es que `l += ingrediente` en el fondo equivale a `l.extend(ingrediente)` y la operación `.extend()` espera que su parámetro sea otro iterable (en este caso lo es, porque una cadena es interable), y entonces itera por él para añadir cada uno de sus elementos (cada letra de la cadena) como nuevos elementos de `l`.

Por cierto que todo ello se podría simplificar a una sola línea:

```
l = s[::-1]
```

porque el operador *slice* devuelve siempre una nueva lista, copia de la original (en este caso al revés por el -1 final).